# Побочная диагональ в матрице (двухмерном массиве)

Tags: c++, массивы

Решаю задачу:
Заполнить матрицу случайными числами. На побочной
диагонали разместить суммы элементов, которые
расположены рядом.

```
int main()
{
    int mas[3][3];
    int i, j, sum;

    srand(time(NULL));
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            mas[i][j] = rand()%10;
            sum = sum + mas[i][j];

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Заполнить случайными числами ячейки смог, а вот понять как заполнить побочную диагональ не могу. Как циклами заполнить побочную матрицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте заодно внесем некоторые поправки и корректность в ваш код

```
const int N = 3;  //  размер менять  нужно только здесь
int mas[N][N];
int  sum = 0;
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  // i и j не нужно сделать внешными 
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        mas[i][j] = rand()%10;  // sum тут не нужно считать, а то получите одно значение
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

И вот ваш код для побочной диагонали, но тут правда я не понел речь идет о сумме каких элементов (которые расположены рядом чего?) Для примера я взял сумму элементов  в каждой строке

```
for (int i = N - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++k) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        sum += mas[i][j];
    mas[i][k] = sum;
    sum = 0;
}
cout << "\n\n";
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

**extra:**  учитывая комментарий относительно того, что является суммой, элементы побочной диагонали могут быть инициализированы следующим образом:

```
 for (int i = N - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++k) { 
        if(!k) 
            sum = mas[N - 2][0] + mas[N - 1][1];        
        else if(!i)
            sum = mas[0][N - 2] + mas[1][N- 1];  
        else
            sum = mas[i - 1][k] + mas[i][k - 1] + mas[i][k + 1] + mas[i + 1][k];
        sum += mas[i][j];
        mas[i][k] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
```

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите суммировать: будет меняться только определение суммы

Comment: Надо найти сумму соседних элементов (те которые лежат рядом с элементами побочной диагонали (справа и слева, снизу и сверху)).

Comment: Хотя, я уже понял как выделить побочную диагональ в цикле. Спсаибо.